# ServerSocket + client Socket - how do I get IP address of client?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have a ServerSocket instance which is listening for connections. When a client connects to it, I would like to get the IP of the connected socket, but can't seem to find the right method to do so.

```
public void start() {
    listenSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    connectionSocket = listenSocket.accept();
}
```

I've tried calling the following with no luck:

```
connectionSocket.getLocalAddress();
connectionSocket.getInetAddress.getHostAddress();
listenSocket.getLocalSocketAddress();
```

None of the above return the correct IP. They either return "/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0" or "0.0.0.0".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The local address is your end. You want the remote address, the other end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
connectionSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
```