# get IP address of a client from a server

Tags: java

i want to a make a software in java as in which one laptop is a server and 1 laptop is a client.The software should get the IP address and all the process running on client .from tutorials i have tried by connecting 2 laptops through LAN and check the connection by sharing a file between the two but when i am using some sort of code to get IP address of client result is null.The code i am using is
[Listing name of or ip of all computers on a LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752292/listing-name-of-or-ip-of-all-computers-on-a-lan)

kindly help me from start that how should i proceed that should i use client server setup for the connection between client and server or as i have mentioned earlier from peer to peer network can i solve my problem. Thankyou

Comment: take alook at this link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558869/getting-ip-address-of-client

Comment: Are you using jsp and servlet

Comment: If you are using TCP sockets between client and server, getRemoteSocketAddress() will return client socket  IP  address of at server end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ServerSocket + client Socket - how do I get IP address of client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421592/serversocket-client-socket-how-do-i-get-ip-address-of-client)

Answer (score 0):

Following my java code:

```
String ipAddress =  request.getRemoteAddr();
System.out.println("IP Address: "+ipAddress);
```